# ember js defining a model for an object containing arrays

Tags: ember.js

here is my code , I have defined a model containing arrays , the problem is that when i send it to the server it does not sends the arrays

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
titre: DS.attr('string'),
categorie: DS.attr('string'),
introduction: DS.attr('string'),
chapitres: [{
    titre: DS.attr('string'),
    introduction: DS.attr('string')
    sousChapitres: [{
        contenu: DS.attr('string'),
        }],
    exercices: [{
        contenu: DS.attr('string')
        }],
    conclusion: DS.attr('string')
    }]
});
```

thank you,

Comment: You can also do `chapitres: DS.attr()` and it'll keep whatever structure is already associated with that key.

Comment: thank you for your response , this method does not send the content of the array to the server , here is an example when i send '{'cour', {
                titre: 'titre',
                categorie: 'categorie',
                introduction: 'introduction',
                chapitres:  [{titre: 'string'}]
            });' i get on the server this '{ cour: 
      { titre: 'titre',
        categorie: 'categorie',
        introduction: 'introduction',
        chapitres: [Object] } },'

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Models for your sub-structures:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    titre: DS.attr('string'),
    categorie: DS.attr('string'),
    introduction: DS.attr('string'),
    chapitres: DS.hasMany('chapitre'),
});

//models/chapitres
export default DS.Model.extend({
    titre: DS.attr('string'),
    introduction: DS.attr('string'),
    exercices: DS.hasMany('exercice'),
});

//models/exercices
export default DS.Model.extend({
    contenu: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Comment: thank you for your response , i did what you said , i get this error message, "Error while processing route: cours.nouveau Assertion Failed: Ember Data expected a number or string to represent the record(s) in the `chapitres` relationship instead it found an object. If this is a polymorphic relationship please specify a `type` key. If this is an embedded relationship please include the `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin` and specify the `chapitres` property in your serializer's attrs object."

Comment: so i added a serializer, for the model , as follow : 
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
   attrs: {
    chapitres: { embedded: 'always'},
  }
});
and i get this error:: Error while processing route: cours.nouveau Assertion Failed: You must include an `id` for chapitre in an object passed to `push`

Comment: All records needs an id. Simple.